# Looping through array updating values PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

say I have an array in php like this

```
$info['name'] = 'test %value%';
$info['city'] = 'city test %value%';
$info['other'] = '%value% city test';
```

all I want to do is loop through this array and replace all the instances of %value% with a supplied string, saving it into the same array.

What would be the best way to do that? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
foreach ($info as $key => $value)
  $info[$key] = str_replace('%value%', 'MyValue', $value);
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/65F3L

Comment: If you want to only replace instances where the entire $value equals your search criteria, rather than instance within the strong, then just wrap the second line in: if ($value == "%value%") {

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be the cleanest way to me, but it requires PHP 5.3 or higher:

```
$info = array_map(function($x) use ($newValue){ 
    return str_replace('%value%', $newValue, $x);
}, $info);
```

[**Codepad**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NeSXH7)